# Updating Parent component state from multiple child components not taking updated state value into account

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question related to react js.

I have a scenario where we have a state in the parent component. It has to be updated by child component. So that, based on the state value, I'll do something else in the parent component.

But, If I render multiple child components, the parent's state is getting updated only once.

Could you please help me understand why the state is updating only once and what would be the possible workaround.

Below is the code sandbox link with the example.

https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-cori-8793u?file=/src/App.js

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that `updateCounter` has closed over the value of `count`, so when you call it twice with two child components the 'old' value of `count` is used both times. You can avoid it by using the 'update' form of `useState`. This ensures that you will increment the 'current' value of `count`:

```
const updateCounter = (num) => {
  setCount(c => c + 1);
  console.log(count);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the doc:

> Unlike the setState method found in class components, useState does not automatically merge update objects.

[doc Link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate).
So you can't pass the old state in a `setState()` like `setCount(count + 1);`.
Because React will "change"  your `count` value during a re-render and in your case you are calling `setCount()` many time before React have the time to render again.
And this is also why your `console.log(count)` displays the previous value.
One solution is this syntax `setState(prevState=> prevState+1)`.
try this:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const updateCounter = () => {
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
  
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Do Something Based On Count Value.");
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox {count}</h1>
      <ChildApp onLoad={updateCounter} />
      <ChildApp onLoad={updateCounter} />
      <ChildApp onLoad={updateCounter} />
    </div>
  );
}

export function ChildApp({ onLoad }) {
  console.log("Child Loaded");
  useEffect(() => {
    onLoad();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[codeSanBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-beaver-gmxum?file=/src/App.js:0-766)